# Unable to deserialize xml array to list web api model c#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api, serialization

Good day guys,
I have been able to serialize my xml to my model in my web api project. But the challenge I have is that the array part or the list part is not getting serialized, its coming out as null.
Please check my xml and model below, the params are not getting mapped.
Thanks

--The Model--

```
[DataContract(Namespace="")]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ValidationRequest")]
public class ValidationRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SourceBankCode")]        
    public string SourceBankCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SourceBankName")]
    public string SourceBankName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "InstitutionCode")]
    public int InstitutionCode { get; set; }        
    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ProductID")]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ProductName")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Param")]
    public List<Param> Param { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Param")]
public class Param
{
    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

-- The XML being passed --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ValidationRequest>
    <SourceBankCode>221</SourceBankCode>
    <SourceBankName>Stanbic IBTC Bank Plc.</SourceBankName>
    <InstitutionCode>999221</InstitutionCode>
    <ProductID>990</ProductID>
    <ProductName>NIBSS ebillsPay</ProductName>
    <Param>
        <Key>Username</Key>
        <Value>3191469</Value>
    </Param>
    <Param>
        <Key>Amount</Key>
        <Value>500</Value>
    </Param>
    <Param>
        <Key>Description</Key>
        <Value>Text Books</Value>
    </Param>
    <Param>
        <Key>DepositorName</Key>
        <Value>Ayomide</Value>
    </Param>
</ValidationRequest>
```

Comment: Are you trying to serialize or deserialize this XML? *The XML being passed* seems to imply that you receive the XML. -- The simplest deserialization possible: `var validation = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ValidationRequest)).Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(xml));` has no problem with it.

Comment: Hi Jimi, sorry for my wrong topic, I will edit it. I want to deserialize. I will try your approach. Thanks

Comment: Hi Jimi, I tried your code, its bringing an error: illegal characters in path

Comment: Hi @Jimi, I have corrected the error, but the array path is still coming out as zero count. Please help check your own results. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try use the below to generate C# class from XML.

https://json2csharp.com/xml-to-csharp

```
// using System.Xml.Serialization;
// XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ValidationRequest));
// using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
// {
//    var test = (ValidationRequest)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
// }

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Param")]
public class Param { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Key")] 
    public string Key { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Value")] 
    public int Value { get; set; } 
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="ValidationRequest")]
public class ValidationRequest { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="SourceBankCode")] 
    public int SourceBankCode { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="SourceBankName")] 
    public string SourceBankName { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="InstitutionCode")] 
    public int InstitutionCode { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="ProductID")] 
    public int ProductID { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="ProductName")] 
    public string ProductName { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Param")] 
    public List<Param> Param { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomson Mixab for the assist, its still not bringing the param list. The count is still zero

Comment: And its always saying there is an error in the xml

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using (var fs = new FileStream("ValidationRequest.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var request = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ValidationRequest)).Deserialize(fs);
}
```

I tried this without any problems. Which .NET version are you using?

Comment: Hi Hao Guo, I'm not fetching the xml from a file, its web api project. Its supposed to map the xml to my object model

Answer (score 0):

Well, at the end of the day, I had to use the hack below, to achieve my purpose, since the array was not mapping automatically.

```
    public ValidationResponse Validation(XElement xml)
    {
        var response = new ValidationResponse();
                    
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml.ToString());
        var str = xmlDoc.InnerXml;

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ValidationRequest));
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(str))
        {
            var test = (ValidationRequest)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("Param");
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    var param = new Param();
                    param.Key = node.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText;
                    param.Value = node.ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText;
                    test.Param.Add(param);
                }
            }
            //rest of other code processes
        }
        return response;
     }
```